# PHP GTK module in php.ini

Tags: command-line, gtk, php

I installed [`PHP GTK`](http://gtk.php.net/) in `C:\php-gtk` but when I go to **run it like from the command** line like this

```
cd C:\php-gtk2
php demos\phpgtk2-demo.php
```

**It gives this error**

```
Please load the php-gtk2 module in your php.ini
```

My **ini file** has this content (it is called `php-cli.ini`)

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About the php.ini in PHP-GTK ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; This file introduces the php.ini settings that you will need in order to
; run PHP-GTK on your system. You may also need other settings from PHP's
; standard php.ini file, e.g. to load further extensions or otherwise control
; PHP's behaviour in matters such as error reporting. Please add those in
; the upper part of this file, in the PHP section.

; You should use PHP's CLI executable to run PHP-GTK. This php.ini file
; should be in the same directory as the PHP executable, to avoid conflict
; with any other copies of PHP that may be installed on your machine.

; The first thing you will need to do is tell PHP where you want it to look
; for the PHP extension libraries (php_*.dll or php_*.so files) on your system.

extension_dir = "./ext"

; Make sure that php-gtk2.dll under Windows, or php-gtk2.so under Unix, is in
; the directory named in extension_dir alongside any other shared PHP extensions
; you intend to use, and tell PHP to load it.

extension = php_gtk2.dll
;extension = php_pdo.**
;extension = php_sqlite.**
;extension = php_pdo_sqlite.**

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
;date.timezone = 

[PHP-GTK]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP-GTK extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Extensions written for PHP-GTK are in the format php_gtk_*.dll (Windows) or
; php_gtk_*.so (Unix), written here as a comma-separated list. The library
; files need to be in the same directory as the PHP-GTK library, along with
; any other PHP extensions you are using.

;php-gtk.extensions = php_gtk_libglade2.dll,php_gtk_sourceview2.dll

;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Code Page ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; The string variables used for titles and other text values in GTK+ are
; encoded in UTF-8 internally. A code page is needed so that PHP-GTK 'knows'
; which character set is being used, and can convert it to UTF-8 as necessary.

; If your environment uses UTF-8 already, you can set the codepage directive
; to UTF-8 to skip the conversions.

; The default codepage setting in PHP-GTK 2 is ISO-8859-1, but you can also
; use either OEM (e.g. 850) or Windows Code Pages (e.g. CP1250) here, so
; long as the encoding format you choose is capable of iconv conversion. See
; http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/reference/cphome.mspx for a list of
; the code pages and character sets that are supported on Windows systems.

php-gtk.codepage = CP1250
```

**What do I need to do?**  Is there ***something wrong with the ini*** file?  Do I need to **rename** it?  What is the problem that is ***tripping up the program?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the **problem was that I needed to call php-gtk** as I had **renamed it already**

Answer (score 2):

you can take it a bit further,  and not worry about paths, I work in Windows environment and I use relative paths even inside .ini like this:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension = php_cairo.dll
extension = php_mongo.dll
```

This allows me to move the php-gtk folder anywhere.

As for running my projects I do a similar thing, I create .cmd files like this:

```
"%CD%\..\..\PhpGtkRuntime\php.exe"  "%CD%\index.php"
```

So you can have for example a central folder and in a subfolder goes php-gtk and in an other one all you projects like this:

```
php-gtk/PhpGtkRuntime 
php-gtk/Projects
```

The whole idea is that I distribute a folder to the final user with a run.cmd inside it and the user does a simple copy paste of the folder, really nothing else. I have made an example package with MongoDB included and all of it is portable even MongoDB, [Check here..](http://php-gtk.eu/en/php-gtk-21-and-mongo-db-server-made-portable-for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Just solved the problem.

I was trying to run the demo script from the demos folder. But when I tried it with the same folder where the php.exe is it ran smoothly. So there is no problem with the php-cli.ini or no need to worry about this error "Please load the php-gtk2 module in your php-cli.ini"

So Goodluck with PHP-GTK.