# Run PHP-GTK Programs without Command Prompt

Tags: php, user-interface, desktop-application, php-gtk

Suppose I have made a project on PHP-GTK. Now how can I run the PHP-GTK without opening the command prompt?

Like in other software, we have a icon on the desktop, by click on that we can run the program, I want to do the same with my program made in PHP-GTK.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a .bat file which executes with a double click. If you are under windows, I guess there must be something similar for unix. This is how you do it for windows:

```
"%CD%\..\..\PhpGtkRuntime\php.exe"  "%CD%\test.php"
```

Of course you will adjust it to your folder depth but the idea is the same.

You can also look this answer which is closely realated and talks about things of immediate interest: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786279/642173)

Answer (score 1):

> this solution workes for me on ***windows XP SP3***

let the phpGtk binary be `C:\monitor\bin\php\php` and the phpGtk main script file to be `C:\monitor\system\monitor ui\monitor.php`

use a bach script (`monitor.bat`) file like this:

```
    @echo off
    rem Hideself
    "C:\monitor\bin\php\php" "C:\monitor\system\monitor ui\monitor.php" %*
    rem Hideself
    pause
```

`rem` is for comments in commands line,
the `%*` part is to pass any arguments provided to the phpGtk script

use this [bat to exe converter](https://web.archive.org/web/20190827213421/https://www.battoexeconverter.com/) to convert Bash `.bat` file to an executable `.exe`

`rem  Hideself` and `rem  Showself` are advanced commands and
they are just what we need
[image: screenshots]

> with this program you can:
>
> ```
>  - set an icon,
>  - include files
>  - set a password for the executable
> ```
>
> > **Hint:** you can phpGtk binarys but you should use `%MyFiles%` to refer to them
> >
> > **Advice:** when your project is all done you can trim the `pause` command (it is just to see the errors php cli logged to you)
> >
> > **Caution:** using multiple icons needs .NET framework
> >
> > **Hint:** you can use [`Ressource Hacker`](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to replace the single icon with multiple ones [image: replace the icon]
> >
> > **Hint:** you can use the [`WinRAR`](https://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0)'s [`SFX` feature](https://www.jackmccarthy.com/malware/WinRAR_Archive_Creation.htm) to handle the installation for you

hope this help somebody's life ! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use Linux, you can create a shell script and put the command with `&` to run in the background?

```
[command] &
```

If you use Windows, try

```
start [command]
```