# Is there a way to make native OS applications

Tags: php, operating-system, winbinder

I was looking for a way to compile simple PHP script to cross platform executble file that can use the OS look and feel.

Do you know how this can be archieved?

Comment: Those are actually two separate questions.  Yes, there are ways to create windows and such.  Yes, I believe I saw something that attempted to wrap up PHP applications into executables, but do not remember the name of it off the top of my head.

Comment: I want to make simple EXE in php to manipulate a config file via GUI

Comment: And... what is the config file? And how do you want to manipulate it?

Comment: Its simple .ini file one setting per line
Just i need OS look-interface

Comment: Do you know any other programming languages?

Comment: I will have to read some :) i know only web languages

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of no cross-platform way to do this in PHP. There are some bindings for specific OSes, but none that would work acceptably on more than one.

Additionally, PHP isn't really an appropriate language to write a desktop application anyway -- Python, Java, or .NET come to mind as better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

there *IS* a way, but actually, php is a script-language designed for the internet...

but if you want to check out, take a look @ http://gtk.php.net/

Also look here [PHP GTK module in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794130/php-gtk-module-in-php-ini/9786279#9786279)

Comment: Hi i find the GTK solution not so stable.

Comment: PHP-GTK is no longer actively developed. Additionally, GTK isn't "native" on Mac OS X.

Comment: for M$ there is phallanger i think, but it's all very unstable, unclean and 100% unreliable ;)

Comment: Yes true :) i will look for other solutions

Comment: Here is the PHP GTK way

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794130/php-gtk-module-in-php-ini/9786279#9786279

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTML + CSS page that replicates the OS, or distribute PHP with your application (much harder).

If your application is simple, you may be able to port it to C++, etc.

*This all depends on what your program does.*

Comment: Thanks i guess i have to write this in some other language 

Too bad php is falling behind in this area, but its good for what is intended to do